# combine sort and uniq functions into 1 in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have `sortBy` and `uniqBy` functions but I iterate over the array twice in a combined `sortUniqBy`.  [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-violet-qvsx4) is a codesandbox and here is the code:

```js
export const sortBy = <T>(o: T[], selector: (item: T) => any): T[] => {
  const result = o.slice(0);

  result.sort((x, y) => {
    const a = selector(x);
    const b = selector(y);

    return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
  });

  return result;
};

export const uniqBy = <T>(o: T[], selector: (item: T) => any): T[] => {
  const ret: T[] = [];

  const set = new Set<T>();

  o.forEach((s) => {
    const value = selector(s);

    if (set.has(value) === false) {
      set.add(value);
      ret.push(s);
    }
  });

  return ret;
};

export const sortedUniqBy = <T>(o: T[], selector: (item: T) => any): T[] => {
  return uniqBy(sortBy(o, selector), selector);
};

sortedUniqBy([1.1, 1.2, 2.3, 2.4], Math.floor); // [1.1, 2.3]
```

Is it possible to somehow sort and remove the duplicates in one loop rather than doing it twice?

Answer (score 2):

You could misuse an object as hash table, which sorts index like keys in order and return the values from it.

```js
function sortedUniqBy(array, callback) {
    const items = {};
    for (const value of array) {
        const temp = callback(value);
        if (!(temp in items) || items[temp] > value) items[temp] = value;
    }
    return Object.values(items);
}

console.log(sortedUniqBy([1.1, 1.2, 2.3, 2.4], Math.floor)); // [1.1, 2.3]
```

Comment: Not sure if of importance but this would provide different results from the author's implementation. For example for case `[2.4, 1.2, 1.1, 2.3]` this would return `[1.1, 2.3]` while authors solution would return `[ 1.1, 2.4 ]`(Basically original solution preserves original order of elements).

Comment: @Aleksey, why sorting in advance?

Comment: Is there a reason you added `items[temp] > value` condition? Without it your solution would be equivalent to author's code.

Comment: i am still not sure, what op is trying to achieve. anyway, if you like to get the first value of a group, remove the mentioned part.